# How can I add array values into a combobox?

Tags: c#, arrays, combobox

I have defined variables as `string` arrays. I also have a form called `form4` and on this form I have 1 textbox and 1 combobox.

I have this code in a class:

```
public class food
{
    public string[] name1 = new string [20];
    public string[] name2 = new string [50];
    public string[] name3 = new string [40] ;
    public string[] name = new string [20];
    public string[] type = new string [15];
    //private const int total = 11;
    public int[] calories_ref;
    public int i, i2;
    public Form4 form = new Form4();


    public food(string[] Name1, string[] Name, string[] Type1, int[] kcal)
    {
        name1 = Name1;
        name = Name;
        type = Type1;
        calories_ref = kcal;
    }
    public food()
    {

    }
    private void settypes()
    {

        type[0] = "Bebidas não alcoólicas";
        type[1] = "Bebidas Alcóolicas";
        type[2] = "Fruta";
        type[3] = "Hidratos de Carbono";
        type[4] = "Peixe";
        type[5] = "Carne";
        type[6] = "Cereais";
        type[7] = "Lacticínios";
        type[8] = "Óleos/Gorduras";
        type[9] = "Leguminosas";
        type[10] = "Legumes";

        for (int i = 0; i < type.Length; i++)
        {
            form.comboBox1.Items.Add(type[i]);
        }
    }
```

In the `settypes()` method I define the various types of food, more concretly the food wheel. How can I can use these values as items in the combobox that is in `form4`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't be storing a `Form4` object in your `food` class. Your code as it is creates a brand new `Form4` every time the `food` object is created. As shown in the line:

```
public Form4 form = new Form4();
```

This won't actually be shown on screen though as you do nothing else with the form except add items to the `ComboBox`, which also wouldn't show on the screen.

Even if you were to get it shown on the screen, you will still get an error similar to:

```
Form4.comboBox1 is inaccessible due to its protection level
```

This is due to the fact that the `ComboBox` is created internally with private access modifier. (See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173121.aspx for more details).

What you need to do is get your existing `Form4` to ask the `food` object to populate it's `ComboBox` by passing the `ComboBox` to a method on the `food` object similar to this example (in your `Form4` code not your `food` code):

```
private void Form4_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    food f = new food(); //or however you wanted to create the object
    f.AddTypesToComboBox(this.comboBox1);
}
```

The `AddTypesToComboBox` method would be defined like this in your `food` object:

```
public void AddTypesToComboBox(ComboBox box)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < type.Length; i++)
    {
        box.Items.Add(type[i]);
    }
}
```

Also, at the moment the function won't actually add anything to the `ComboBox` as your `type` array is not being filled with data. You need to call `settypes();` in the `food` object's constructors like this:

```
public food(string[] Name1, string[] Name, string[] Type1, int[] kcal)
{
    settypes();
    name1 = Name1;
    name = Name;
    type = Type1;
    calories_ref = kcal;
}
public food()
{
    settypes();
}
```

You will need to remove `public Form4 form = new Form4();` from your variable declaration section as well as removing the following from your `settypes()` method:

```
for (int i = 0; i < type.Length; i++)
{
    form.comboBox1.Items.Add(type[i]);
}
```

Your `settypes()` should only fill the data into the array, and not try and add it to the `ComboBox`.

Comment: form.comboBox1.Items.AddRange(type);

Answer (score 11):

You can add an array of strings using method `AddRange(array[])` from `comboBox`.

```
form.comboBox1.Items.AddRange(type);
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a void you can use if you want to go beyond just one array.

```
public void AddToCombo(Array array, ComboBox c)
{
  foreach(var a in array)
  {
    c.Items.Add(a);
  }
}
```

Comment: That is a foreach loop, quite different than a for loop. Also, what is the point of having it in its own method?

Comment: Sorry, I got off track lol.
Anyways, I just thought he could use it if he wanted to add the other arrays also.

Comment: I think you intend to clear the items before you add new ones.. no?

Comment: I guess you could, but it wouldn't be a void that would be suitable for any comboBox.

Comment: (sorry can't help it) `void` is just the return type, it's actually a **method**. (feel better now - didn't mean to sound harsh if I did)

Answer (score 1):

If you want the items to be in the ComboBox just set the array as its datasource.  You don't need to loop through the array and add the items one by one.  It's a lot less code than the other solutions here.

```
    public void SetTypes()
    {
        comboBox1.DataSource = new[]{
            "Bebidas não alcoólicas",
            "Bebidas Alcóolicas",
            "Fruta",
            "Hidratos de Carbono",
            "Peixe",
            "Carne",
            "Cereais",
            "Lacticínios",
            "Óleos/Gorduras",
            "Leguminosas",
            "Legumes"
        };
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Not at my computer at the moment, but this should do it:

```
    foreach(var type in type[])
    {
        form.comboBox1.Items.Add(type);
    }
```

Comment: i will try ... tomorrow. Tank you

Comment: @VitorFerreira - Ok, hope it works out fine. Would you mind marking this answer with an up vote in the mean time?

Answer (score 0):

As simple as this:

```
public void yourMethodName() {        
    yourComboBoxName.removeAllItems();
    for (YourObjectName object: yourArrayListName) {
        yourComboBoxName.addItem(object.getWhatYouWanaGet());
    }        
}
```

Your remove the actual item from the list than you add the item you want to add :)

Answer (score 0):

If this is an Array in `Class1`:

```
public static string[] session = new string[] { "2023-2024", "2022-2023","2021-2022" };
```

In C# (Windows Forms):

```
comboBox1.Items.Clear();
comboBox1.Items.AddRange(Class1.session);
```